Weird thing in cpp[x86-64 gcc 13.1]: the compiler thinks the if condition is always true
I'm working on an algorithmic topic and I'm running into a strange bug. when I put the source code on Complier Explorer and look at the assembly code, I seem to find out what's causing the problem, but I don't understand it.
Picture1:
enter image description here
Picture2:
enter image description here
When I use if(0 <= start) in Picture1, that's ok and the code works fine.
But when I use if(0 <= j - wordDict[i].size() + 1) in Picture2, the process throw an error about "basic_string::substr: __pos (which is 18446744073709551613) > this->size() (which is 8)".
Reading the assembly code [Line84-86] when using if(0 <= j - wordDict[i].size() + 1), it's apparently that %al is always 1 and the pc will not jump to L52 from line:86, which seems to indicate that the compiler believes that the if(0 <= j - wordDict[i].size() + 1) condition will always hold true.
Why does the compiler cause this?
Looking forward to someone addressing my query or pointing out my mistake.
Here is the complete code:
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
using namespace std;
bool wordBreak(string s, vector<string>& wordDict) {

    vector<bool> dp(s.size(), false);
    unordered_set<string> all(wordDict.begin(), wordDict.end());

    for (int j = 0; j < s.size(); j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < wordDict.size(); i++)
        {
            int start = j - wordDict[i].size() + 1;
            if (0 <= (j - wordDict[i].size() + 1))
            {
                string word = s.substr(j - wordDict[i].size() + 1, wordDict[i].size());
                if (all.find(word) != all.end() && (j - wordDict[i].size() + 1 == 0 || dp[j - wordDict[i].size()]))
                {
                    dp[j] = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return dp[s.size()-1];
}

int main(int args, char * argv[])
{
    string s = "leetcode";
    vector<string> wordDict = {"leet","code"};
    wordBreak (s, wordDict);
    return 0;
}


You should also post the complete code here on SO. Adding a link is optional but the code must always be available on SO.

I am on mobile so, short hint. The condition will always be true because unsigned int cannot be negative. Check j before performing the substraction.

It's common to write a >= b or b <= a rather than 0 <= a - b, and a == b rather than a - b == 0.

@flydev. Thanks, the key is wordDict[i].size(), which return unsigned type on most compliers.

You should always compile with warnings enabled. With -Wextra, you get https://godbolt.org/z/937zxjxEz
<source>:14:19: warning: comparison of unsigned expression in '>= 0' is always true [-Wtype-limits]
   14 |             if (0 <= (j - wordDict[i].size() + 1))
      |                 ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

int{} - std::vector<std::string>::size_type{} + int{} is std::vector<std::string>::size_type on most compilers (since std::vector<std::string>::size_type is std::size_t which is unsigned long, so the int promotes to unsigned long)
A value of an unsigned type will always be >= 0.
Just make sure there won't be an overflow by not subtracting:
// Add wordDict[i].size() to both sides
if (0 + wordDict[i].size() <= j - wordDict[i].size() + 1 + wordDict[i].size())
if (wordDict[i].size() <= j + 1)

And probably change the types of i and j to std::size_t too.

Thank you for your reply, I think I understand completely. I'll pay attention to the use of -Wextra afterward!

Just one small addition: If you don't type your start variable but use auto, you would probably get the same behaviour as putting it inline into the if clause. In any case, using auto is very useful, especially because you then get the correct type for the expression, independent of environment.
